# Checkbox value return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello guys i have a problem, i have a 2 checkbox, each of them have value. The first checkbox is Any/Not, and the second one is Valid/Invalid. If the checkbox is checked the value will change to Any, if not checked the value will be not, same for the valid/invalid one.

I already tried, but when the checkbox is unchecked the value im getting is undefined. Btw i use react, node, and mysql. But the value is succesfully changed when the box is checked.

[image: Here is the result from database :]

Here is the code :

**FormDataProvider.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {createContext, useState} from "react"
export const FormData = createContext();
export default function FormDataProvider({children}) {
    const [formData , setFormData] = useState({
        cName : "",
        Address : "",
        phoneNumber : "",
        presidentName : "",
        managerEmail : "",
        managerPhone : "",
        picEmail : "",
        picPhone : "",
        date: "",
        mainBusiness : "",
        employeeNumber : "",
        numberOfCustomer : "",
        myFile : "",
        any : "" ,
        valid : ""
      });
  return (
    <FormData.Provider value={{ formData, setFormData }}>
     {children}
    </FormData.Provider>
  );
}
```

**Form.js**

```
const Form = () => {

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  

    const { emailLog, setEmailLog } = useContext(EmailUser);
    const { loginStatus, setLoginStatus } = useContext(LoginStatus);
    const { formData , setFormData} = useContext(FormData);


  
    const handleChange = event => {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        setFormData({...formData, any : event.target.checked})
      } else {
        setFormData({...formData, any : "Not"})
      }
    };

    const handleChange2 = event => {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        setFormData({...formData, valid : event.target.checked})
      } else {
        setFormData({...formData, valid : "Invalid"})
      }
    };

   
   
  return (
    <form method='POST' encType='multipart/form-data' action='http://localhost:3001/registration'>
    <div className=''>
      <input className='inputForm' type='email' value={emailLog} name='email' required onChange={(e) => {
        setEmailLog(e.target.value) }} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='text' placeholder='Company Name' name="CompanyName" required value={formData.cName}  onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, cName: event.target.value })}/>
      <input className='inputForm' type='text' placeholder='Address' name="Address" required value={formData.Address} onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, Address: event.target.value })}  />
      <input className='inputForm' type='tel' placeholder='Phone Number' name="Phone" required value={formData.phoneNumber} onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({ ...formData, phoneNumber: event.target.value })}  />
      <input className='inputForm' type='text' placeholder='President Director Name' name="PresidentName" required value={formData.presidentName} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, presidentName: event.target.value})} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='email' placeholder='Manager Email' name="ManagerEmail" required value={formData.managerEmail} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, managerEmail: event.target.value})}  />
      <input className='inputForm' type='tel'  placeholder='Manager Phone' name="ManagerPhone" required value={formData.managerPhone} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, managerPhone: event.target.value})} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='email'  placeholder='PIC Email' name="PICEmail" required value={formData.picEmail} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, picEmail: event.target.value})} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='tel'  placeholder='PIC Phone' name="PICPhone" required value={formData.picPhone} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, picPhone: event.target.value})} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='date'  placeholder='Date' name="EstablishedDate" required value={formData.date} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, date: event.target.value})} />
        <select className='selectBox' name='ChoiceBusiness' required onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({...formData, mainBusiness: event.target.value})} >
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Main Business...</option>
                  <option value="Software License">Software License</option>
                  <option value="IT Services & Consulting">IT Services & Consulting</option>
                  <option value="IT Outsourcing">IT Outsourcing</option>
                  <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                  <option value="General Trading">General Trading</option>
                  <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
        <select className='selectBox' name='EmployeeNumber' required onChange={(event) =>
          setFormData({...formData, employeeNumber: event.target.value})} >
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Employee Number...</option>
                <option value="1-50">1-50</option>
                <option value="51-100">51-100</option>
                <option value="101-250">101-250</option>
                <option value="251-500">251-500</option>
                <option value="500+">500+</option>
        </select>
      <input className='inputForm' type="number"  placeholder='Number of Customer' name="NumberOfCustomer" required value={formData.numberOfCustomer} onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, numberOfCustomer: event.target.value})} />

      <input className='inputFormDate' type="file" name='pdfFiles' multiple required onChange={(event) => 
          setFormData({...formData, myFile : event.target.value})}  />


        <div className='formCheckboxes'>
          <div className='formCheckbox'>
              <p>SK Menhum & Akta Notaris</p>
             
             

          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Any"  name="Any" onChange={handleChange}/>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">Any</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Valid"  name="Valid" onChange={handleChange2}/>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">Valid</label>
          </div>
        
                      
        </div>
 </div>
          
          <button className='btnSubmit' type='submit'> Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  )
}


export default Form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Always use the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) format to update state based on its previous value to prevent loss of batched state updates.
2. When checked, you're setting the value to the `checked` property which is a Boolean. You want the `value` property instead

Try something like this

```js
setFormData((fd) => ({
  ...fd,
  any: event.target.checked ? event.target.value : "Not",
}));
```

---

You could probably use something generic for all inputs provided their `name` attributes match the object keys you want.

Checkboxes could provide their *off* value in a data-attribute, eg

```html
<input
  class="form-check-input"
  type="checkbox"
  value="Any"
  data-off="None"
  name="any"
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

```js
// generic handler for all inputs
const handleChange = (e) => {
  let value;
  switch (e.target.type) {
    case "checkbox":
      value = e.target.checked ? e.target.value : e.target.dataset.off;
      break;
    case "file":
      value = e.target.files[0];
      break;
    default:
      value = e.target.value;
  }

  setFormData((fd) => ({
    ...fd,
    [e.target.name]: value,
  }));
};
```

Comment: I would not waste my time with the value field if you're not submitting it a form, just leave it off entirely and `any: event.target.checked ? "Any" : "Not",` and move on. It is react, you should be shoving state down, not reading it off the dom. (When it is not user driven entry like a text box or simply checked state).

Comment: it s a form with checkbox, image, and all data (sry for not explain cleary)